# R chart convert to html format without other files

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly, r-plotly

My sample dataset:

```
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

d <-
  data.frame(
    "name" = c("bily", "mary", "ken"),
    "fruit" = c("cherry", "apple", "apple"),
    "count" = c(1, 10, 30)
  )

gg <- ggplot(data = d,
             aes(x = fruit,
                 y = count,
                 group = name)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = name)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = name))

plotly <- ggplotly(gg)
```

save graph:

```
d <- # please put your directory where you want to save the graph
  "xxxx/graph.html"
```

I have searched these three functions that can output the HTML format but they will also make other files and I cannot solve it.

```
  #htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(plotly), d)
  #htmltools::browsable(plotly)
  htmltools::save_html(plotly, d)
```

I am trying to convert my graph, which uses from ggplot function to ggplotly function, to HTML format but I face a problem. When I save the graph, the function will also make other files such as plotlyjs, jquery, and crosstalk. I hope only the HTML file can be made because it is too hard to put the files on the website if each graph has different files.

These are the files when I run the code. My expected result is that only the HTML file is made.

[image]

The other files are saved in the directory of the lib but I hope they are not provided and I can run the HTML file. Is it possible to do? or Are there any other methods?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `selfcontained = TRUE` to your last line:

```
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(plotly), selfcontained = TRUE, file = "xxxx/graph.html")
```

Comment: I tried but there are still other files such as jquery,typedarray and htmlwidgets. Is it possible to make the HTML file only without other files?

Comment: I just rerun the code and I see two files: one folder names graph_files and one doc called graph.html. And you can use graph.html by itself

Comment: it can't as the graph.html relies on the graph_files,which includes other files such as jquery,typedarray and htmlwidgets.

Comment: no just moved the graph.html to a different location and just open it

Comment: yes, I know what you mean but if the graph_files are not there. The graph.html will show nothing.

Comment: I don't get it. It works delete the graph_files and you will see graph.html is still working. it is clearly explained here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/htmlwidgets/versions/0.9/topics/saveWidget

Comment: oh, sorry I made mistakes. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: no worries, you can also accept the answer if it works for you!