# How to store r ggplot graph as html code snippet

Tags: r, ggplot2, htmltools

I am creating an html document by creating various objects with `ggplotly()` and htmltools functions like `h3()` and `html()`.  Then I submit them as a list to `htmltools::save_html()` to create an html file.

I would like to add ggplot charts directly as images, rather than attaching all the plotly bells and whistles. In the end, I will create a self-contained html file (no dependencies), and the plotly stuff would make that file excessively large.

Is there some function that converts a ggplot object into some html-type object?  Or do I have to save the ggplot as a .png file, then read the .png file into some object that I add to the list in the save_html() function?

My R code looks something like this:

```
library("tidyverse")
library("plotly")
library("htmltools")

HTMLOut <- "c:/Users/MrMagoo/My.html")
df <- data.frame(x=1:25, y=c(1:25*1:25))

g7 <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point()
p7 <- ggplotly(g7)  # I would like to use something other than ggplotly here. Just capturing the ggplot as an image would be fine.

# create other objects to add to the html file
t7 <- h2(id="graph7", "Title for graph #7")
d7 <- p("description of graph 7")

save_html(list(t7, p7, d7), HTMLOut)
# of course, the real code has many more objects in that list – more graphs, text, tables, etc.
```

I would like to replace the plotly object (p7) with something that just presents g7 in a way that would not cause an error in the save_html function.

I had hoped to find a function that could directly **Base64 encode** a ggplot object, but it seems that I first need to output the 'ggplot' object as a .png file (or SVG, per Teng L, below), then base64-encode it.  I was hoping there was a more direct way, but I may end up doing that, as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33410766/3799203 , ending it with

```
g7img <- "<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,(base64encode string)\""
g7img <- htmltools::html(g7img)
```

Comment: have you seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48497704/r-chart-convert-to-html-format-without-other-files)

Comment: Thanks, I did see that post. I would like to avoid plotly, because the self-contained html file it creates are large (over two megabytes), to support all the interactive functions it provides.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up generating a temparory image file, then base64 encoding it, within a function I called `encodeGraphic()` (borrowing code from [LukeA's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33410766/3799203)):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RCurl)
library(htmltools)
encodeGraphic <- function(g) {
  png(tf1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".png"))  # Get an unused filename in the session's temporary directory, and open that file for .png structured output.
  print(g)  # Output a graphic to the file
  dev.off()  # Close the file.
  txt <- RCurl::base64Encode(readBin(tf1, "raw", file.info(tf1)[1, "size"]), "txt")  # Convert the graphic image to a base 64 encoded string.
  myImage <- htmltools::HTML(sprintf('<img src="data:image/png;base64,%s">', txt))  # Save the image as a markdown-friendly html object.
  return(myImage)
}

HTMLOut <- "~/TEST.html"   # Say where to save the html file.
g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear,y=mpg,group=factor(am),color=factor(am))) + geom_line()  # Create some ggplot graph object
hg <- encodeGraphic(g)  # run the function that base64 encodes the graph
forHTML <- list(h1("My header"), p("Lead-in text about the graph"), hg)
save_html(forHTML, HTMLOut)  # output it to the html file.
```

Comment: is there a way to control the width of the image.

Comment: Is there a way to use the htm code 'forHTML' and still being interactive as a real plotly plot? I wonder cause i struggle to add a plotly plot in a Wordpress post or page as a html output...but with the html code 'forHTML' is works...though its not interactive anymore...

Answer (score 12):

If you want to save the plot as a dynamic `plotly` graph, you could use `htmlwidgets::saveWidget`. This will produce a stand-alone html file.

Here is a minimal example:

```
library(tidyverse);
library(plotly);
library(htmlwidgets);

df <- data.frame(x = 1:25, y = c(1:25 * 1:25))
gg <- ggplot(df,aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()

# Save ggplotly as widget in file test.html
saveWidget(ggplotly(gg), file = "test.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want may be close to one of the following:

1. Seems you are creating an HTML report but hasn't checked out [RMarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com). It comes with **Base64 encode**. When you create an RMarkdown report, `pandoc` automatically converts any plots into an HTML element within the document, so the report is self-contained.
2. SVG plots. This is less likely to be what you might want, but SVG plots are markup-language based and may be easily portable. Specify `.svg` extension when you use `ggsave()` and you should be getting an SVG image. Note that SVG is an as-is implementation of the plot, so if can be huge in file size if you have thousands of shapes and lines.

Comment: SVG may be an OK solution. I added more to my original post about saving the ggplot to a file.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension to [the Maurits Evers post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50244795/1613005). In this answer I'm showing h**ow to combine multiple plotly plots in the same html** file in an organized fashion:

```r
library("plotly")
library("htmltools")

# a small helper function to avoid repetition
my_func <- function(..., title){
    ## Description:
    ##   A function to add title to put multiple gg plotly objects under a html heading
    ##
    ## Arguments:
    ##   ...: a list of gg objects
    ##   title: a character vector to specify the heading text
    
    # get the ... in list format
    lst <- list(...)
    
    # create the heading
    tmp_title <- htmltools::h1(title)
    
    # convert each ggplot to ggplotly and put them under the same div html tag
    tmp_plot <- lapply(lst, ggplotly) |>
        htmltools::div()
    
    # return the final object as list
    return(list(tmp_title, tmp_plot))
}

# a toy data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:25, y = c(1:25 * 1:25))

# the ggplot object using the toy data
gg <- ggplot(df,aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()

# put everything in order
final_list <- list(my_func(obj = list(gg, gg, gg), title = "The first heading"),
                   my_func(obj = list(gg, gg), title = "The second heading"))

# write to disk as a unified HTML file
htmltools::save_html(html = final_list,
                     file = "index.html"))
```

Disclaimer: I specifically did this to avoid using widgetframe R package and to be completely on par with [the documentation of plotly-r](https://plotly-r.com/saving.html). You can read the link if you are comfortable with adding extra dependency and extra abstraction layer. I prefer to use packages if and only if necessary. :)